# How do I change 3 different types of dates to be the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data coming from 3 separate entities that include dates of birth.  Some of the data has the date as 2001/12/02, some has it as 20011202, and some has it as 12/02/2001.  Is there a way to normalize this data so that it is all the same format?

Comment: So, uh, how do you know `12/02/2001` is m/d/y and not d/m/y?

Comment: @AaronBertrand You can't see/know from a single date but usually in a file all dates are in the same format and if you find, say, a 31/02/2001 you know enough ;-)

Comment: @Robill Yes, I know that, I want to make sure the OP is really sure, because if there is an assumption based on one date (or multiple dates that don't go past the 12th of any month), the difference between style 101 and 103 is a pretty important one. Also they say "3 separate entities" so "in a file" is not really matching their reality.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That is a valid point.  The original data sources are coming from different districts, and then someone else uploads them to a database, where I am charged with combining and comparing all the data from the different data sources.  So you are absolutely correct, wondering if the different date formats are even close to the same.  It is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your desired output is December 2, 2001  ... `try_convert()` should do the trick

I should add that `try_convert()` will return a `NULL` if the conversion fails, rather than throwing an error.

```
Select try_convert(date,'2001/12/02')
      ,try_convert(date,'20011202')
      ,try_convert(date,'12/02/2001')
```

**Results**

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
2001-12-02          2001-12-02          2001-12-02
```

Comment: I would explicitly list the styles expected (111, 108, 101) in case they use datetime or immediately discover that last one is actually d/m/y and they need 103 instead. [e.g.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ade3c9a554807c2c5806b795823a3086)

Comment: (Note also this can transpose with `date`, too, so it's not restricted to the legacy date/time types. Basically, `convert` from string to date is hard to trust without an explicit style and, I know you know this, but getting NULL or the wrong date is arguably worse than getting an exception: [e.g.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b335efc88648dcc6b5d4db95332b5a7d)).

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Respectfully, disagree.   NULLs are easy to isolate as part of your data hygiene routines.   ABENDs tend to panic people.

Comment: You can disagree that expecting Dec 2nd but storing Feb 12th is better than an error, but I can assure you that isn't universally what all orgs would prefer. As written, your code can transpose month and day depending on the language of the user, and while that may be what you want, you better be sure the reader knows that. (Putting style numbers there avoids the problem entirely.)

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have a table with a single column, and it has some inconsistent data in it:

```
CREATE TABLE #InconsistentFormats
(
  RegionalDate varchar(20)
);

INSERT #InconsistentFormats(RegionalDate)
  VALUES('2001/12/02'), ('20011202'), ('12/02/2001');
```

Assuming you *know* the formats are limited to `yyyy/MM/dd`, `yyyyMMdd`, and `mm/DD/yyyy`, you can do this by just wrapping `TRY_CONVERT()` - with explicit [conversion style numbers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) - inside `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT TheRealDate = COALESCE
(
  TRY_CONVERT(date, RegionalDate, 111), -- yyyy/MM/dd
  TRY_CONVERT(date, RegionalDate, 108), -- yyyyMMdd
  TRY_CONVERT(date, RegionalDate, 101)  -- MM/dd/yyyy 
)
FROM #InconsistentFormats;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ace2a1661980cb11c413338b9e026fa)

Without the style numbers, watch what happens when you have, say, a different language:

```
SET LANGUAGE British;

SELECT TheRealDate = TRY_CONVERT(date, RegionalDate) 
FROM #InconsistentFormats;
```

[One of the dates gets transposed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0879c854279e5b9285f29d2f0f7fa2d6) (and would become NULL if it was a day after the 12th).

Some might think that storing February 12th (or NULL) instead of the expected December 2nd is better than an exception, but I don't think everyone would agree. While some people might have great data hygiene processes that will find that NULL or flipped date immediately, many people don't, and they could be losing or corrupting data for 12 days before they realize it.